# Como saber cuales son los Archivos (links y scripts) requeridos en una pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css, script, enlace

Tengo una pagina html en la que se debe mostrar un formulario con muchos controles personalizados, pero al cargarla no se ve como debe, se que me hacen falta algunos .js y .css pero no se cuales, también se que el orden en que se llamen es relevante...
Existe alguna herramienta o utilidad que me permita saber cuales son los link y los scripts que utiliza determinada pagina para cargar correctamente? y que ademas, diga cual es el orden para llamarlos?

Comment: Hola, deberías de ver [como hacer una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que puedan ayudarte. Muestra lo que tienes conseguido hasta ahora, para ello te puedes [hacer el tour del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) nuevamente, para poder incluir tu código, y poder ayudarte. Muestra lo que tienes y tratare de ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia Miguel, en mi caso es un formulario con inputs, selects, etc. Pero mi pregunta aplica para cualquier pagina en general, conoces alguna herramienta que haga lo que deseo?

Comment: Muestra el código y empezamos a ver lo que necesitas. Estaré encantado de ayudarte en lo que pueda, pero sin ver lo que tienes. Como guía, puedes, puedes: Pinchar en cualquier página, con el segundo botón => ver código fuente y hacerte una idea de cómo está echa. Para un formulario necesitas muy pocas cosas. En esta [pregunta que yo hice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127763/como-separo-en-dos-cuadros-diferentes-los-datos-del-formulario) veras un poco la estructura de un formulario . Luego te busco plantillas de formularios

Comment: Al menos que yo conozca, no existe una herramienta de esas características. Si lo que quieres es tener control sobre las dependencias, podrías usar Webpack, pero no es algo trivial adaptar lo que ya tienes. https://webpack.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

> Existe alguna herramienta o utilidad que me permita saber cuales son los link y los scripts que utiliza determinada pagina para cargar correctamente? y que ademas, diga cual es el orden para llamarlos?

- el inspector del navegador (la forma mas practica de levantar el inspector es haciendo click derecho y seleccionando la opción "Inspeccionar" o "Inspeccionar Elemento") te puede dar información muy util en la sección "Network" (o "Red" dependiendo del idioma que tengas configurado) sobre que archivos se cargaron o no correctamente.

Comment: Conozco bien los recursos de los navegadores... la opción que mencionas no me dice cuales links o scripts faltan por incluir. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Te dice los errores y si te faltó un archivo local. No puede adivinar qué archivos no pusiste a tu página.